# Do I need to submit a sitemap to Google with new filename everytime I have new URLs?

Tags: seo, google-search-console

I just submitted my first sitemap to Webmaster Tools a few days ago. Now I just added some new pages to my site and I'm not sure that I should create a new sitemap or just extend the existing.

So which option is the right?

1. Adding the new URLs to my existing sitemap (*sitemap1.xml*) and doesn't change anything.
2. Creating a new sitemap called *sitemap2.xml* and submitting it as well to Webmaster Tools.

Or maybe it doesn't really matter and I can choose the option I like? Is there any SEO related danger if I delete the old sitemap and submit the new one (with a new name and URL)?

Comment: It sounds like you expect the sitemap to help your new pages get indexed or ranked in some way.   That isn't the case.   Sitemaps allow you to see additional stats in Google Search Console, but they have no impact on rankings.  See: [The Sitemap Paradox](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4803/the-sitemap-paradox)

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Yes, I'm asking this because I assumed if I submit a new sitemap the new pages will be crawled faster.